# Drawing pdfpage in context with uitabbarcontroller

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, cgcontext

I have a uiviewcontroller that contains a pdf.

The pdf is drawed in the viewcontroller's context and is partially covered by the navigation bar on top and the tabbar on bottom (this is what i want).

I want to hide the two bars with a double tap and visualize the full pdf page.

The problem is that the bottom part of the pdf is not drawed and when i hide the bottom tabBar this fact becomes evident (the hiding of the navigation bar on top works well).

My question is: how is possible to draw the pdf in the "full" context after the hiding of bottombar?

(I have already tried to use `setNeedsDisplay` to force the redrawing, but the context is still the same after the bars hiding)

Following is the code that draws the pdf page:

```
-(void)drawLayer:(CALayer*)layer inContext:(CGContextRef)ctx
```

{

```
CGContextSetRGBFillColor(ctx, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
CGContextFillRect(ctx, self.bounds);
CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, 0.0, self.bounds.size.height);
CGContextScaleCTM(ctx, 1.0, -1.0);
CGContextConcatCTM(ctx, CGPDFPageGetDrawingTransform(pdfPage,kCGPDFMediaBox,self.bounds, 0, true));
CGContextDrawPDFPage(ctx, pdfPage);
```

}

the code that initializes the bars (in the appdelegate):

```
tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

MagazineViewController *magazineViewController = [[MagazineViewController alloc] init];
NewsTableViewController *newsViewController = [[NewsTableViewController alloc] init];
VideoViewController *videoViewController = [[VideoViewController alloc] init];

UINavigationController *magazineNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:magazineViewController];  
UINavigationController *newsNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:newsViewController];  
UINavigationController *videoNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:videoViewController];

magazineNavigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
newsNavigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
videoNavigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];

NSArray *tabsArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:magazineNavigationController, newsNavigationController, videoNavigationController, nil];

tabBarController.viewControllers = tabsArray;

[window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

And the code that hides the bars:

```
for (UINavigationController *controller in tabBarController.viewControllers) {
        if(controller.navigationBar.topItem.title == @"Magazine") {
            [controller setNavigationBarHidden:(!controller.navigationBar.hidden) animated:YES];
            tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = !tabBarController.tabBar.hidden;
            [self setNeedsDisplay];
            return;
        }
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the code that hides your bars, here:

```
[controller setNavigationBarHidden:(!controller.navigationBar.hidden) animated:YES];
tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = !tabBarController.tabBar.hidden;
```

The first line is a helper method that removes the nav bar for you - so it removes itself from view nicely. 
The second line is just changing the 'hidden' property - so it does not remove itself very nicely.

In order to get the tab bar hiding nicely and **not clipping your context** is to adjust its frame. Here's a [nice example](http://www.developers-life.com/hide-uitabbarcontrolleruitabbar-with-animation.html), or you can just set the frame on your tab bar like:

*swap with the second line*

```
tabBarController.tabBar.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,0,0);
```

Comment: Thank you, with the example the animation is working well, but the pdf remains clipped by the invisible bottom bar.

Answer (score -1):

NSLog the self.bounds, heres a nice toolbox function:

```
-(NSString*)getStringFromCGRect:(CGRect)rect WithLabel:(NSString*)idName
{


return [NSString stringWithFormat:@">%@\nx:%f\ny:%f\nWidth:%f\nHeight:%f\n\n",idName,rect.origin.x,rect.origin.y,rect.size.width,rect.size.height];
}
```

I would guess that your bounds will be your view size-your toolbar heights, if its not that are you you configuring any `CALayer`'s when you create your drawing class?

Comment: Nice function, but it won't reveal much in this case.

Comment: An unnessesary dv in my opinion

Comment: The rect size is correct (320 x 460) but the pdf remains clipped. I am not configuring any CALayer, but now i'm trying to draw ovverriding -(void)drawRect:(CGRect)r but the result is the same

Comment: what about the bounds/frame of the layer your drawing the context in?